# Implementing a dynamic File Transfer Controller using ThreadPoolExecutor in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, io, java.util.concurrent, threadpoolexecutor

I recently had to implement a Controller that's transfering files from A to B. 
There are about 8000 files with 1-2 mb size each.

- If one file transfer succeeds, create another thread. ( currently increase corePooleSize +1 )
- If one file transfer fails, close one thread retry transfer.( currently increase corePooleSize -1 )
- If one file transfer fails, don't create another thread for a certain time.

The idea behind this is to get the maximum possible number of connections/ best transfer speed without knowing the limitations of the host.

Now my question is, is a ThreadPoolExecutor the best way to implement this behaviour or is there a better way?

```
//Code simplified
//add all files to callables with type Future<Boolean>
while (true) {

   // entry = get the first result that's done.

   if (entry.getValue().get() == Boolean.TRUE) {
       results.remove(entry.getKey());
       if (results.size() > threadPool.getCorePoolSize()) {

           if (System.currentTimeMillis() >= nextAttempt)
               resizeThreadPool(+1);
       }
   } else {
       resizeThreadPool(-1);
       nextAttempt = System.currentTimeMillis() + someTimeinMs;
       entry.setValue(threadPool.submit(entry.getKey()));
   }
   if (results.isEmpty())
      return true;
}
```

Edit: There is a minimum & maximum number of threads given as parameter.

Comment: You need to rethink this completely. There is nothing about your computation that has anything to do with 'best transfer speed', so you will end up creating an enormous number of threads, all thrashing and competing with each other for the CPU and network and getting absolutely nowhere. The maximum number of threads you should use is the path bandwidth divided by the target transfer rate. You will find this number is rather small.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty interesting problem in that you have variable performance per file transfer (reads/writes can happen on the local disk or at some remote location, and not all disks/network locations have the same effective bandwidth available at all times).  I'm not sure that using transfer success/failure is a good metric for deciding when you should increase or reduce your thread count, however. I suspect that failures will not happen as a result of over-provisioning read/write locations with threads, they will probably just slow down, incurring some added overhead when compared to copying one file at a time.  In that case, you will just spawn more threads until you run out of files to copy or run out of memory, whichever comes first.

That said, I think you may be better off approaching the problem from a different angle. The following constraints are foremost in my mind:

1. You must read each file *from* somewhere.
2. You must write each file *to* somewhere.
3. Read/Write locations are arbitrary.
4. You can't fit every file into RAM before writing it.
5. You can't spawn an infinite number of threads (you'll run out of memory if you try).

With these constraints in mind, I would maintain a couple of thread pools, one for reads and one for writes, with each pool polling a queue of read/write requests. In the optimal case, a new thread would be spawned with each new read/write location discovered, but capped at a certain size so you don't exceed your system memory limits (or some predetermined acceptable amount). You'd also want to set some buffer size where, if the file is larger than that buffer size, you'll read the first N bytes, then pass those bytes to the write queue before reading the next N bytes. This way you can start writing large files to their destination before they've been read in their entirety, saving you the time and memory it would require to read the entire file before writing it. Finally, you can limit the write queue size to prevent your program from reading more data than you can fit into your program's RAM allocation at any given time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and I wasn't satisfied with my solution either. I forgot to mention that I have to parameters, one minimum and maximum poolsize. To your points 1. & 2.: All read & write operations are already implemented. I can't modify them and just get their complete transfer method as callable.

All locations I read/write are remote, eg. Google Cloud Storage, S3... But also FTP and the FTP server I am using rejects every connection above 30. 

I start the transfer with 25 threads. It will increase till 31, then fail and continue with 30.